# Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 - I can build and run on devices, but not for simulators

Tags: ios, linker-errors

When I run it on simulator I getting this error,

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_SecPolicyCreateSSL",
>   referenced from:
>   "_SecTrustSetPolicies", referenced from:
>   "_SecTrustGetCertificateCount", referenced from:
>   "_SecTrustGetCertificateAtIndex", referenced from:
>   "_SecTrustCreateWithCertificates", referenced from:
>   "_SecTrustEvaluate", referenced from: ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64

Comment: Framework you are using is not supported simulator architecture

Comment: Try to run the project in Real device. It will work

Comment: Yes its working in real device, but not in simulator @manishsharma93

Comment: Now its working, i found 2 security frameworks so i deleted old one. Thanks for your concern @Prashant Tukadiya, manishsharma93

Answer (score 0):

Your framework doesn't support simulator you can try this

```
import Foundation
#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
import YourFramework
#endif

// For using

#if !targetEnvironment(simulator)
    YourFramework.setup()
#endif
```

If you have bridge header you can use too for import